# Laravel logging treshhold

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-5

I am configuring monolog logging in laravel and I am wondering if there is a way to specify threshold for log file? For example in log4php you have maxFileSize property. Is there some way to do it with monolog?

(Check this for how to configure custom monolog:  [Configuring Custom Logging in Laravel 5](https://blog.muya.co.ke/configure-custom-logging-in-laravel-5/)  )

According to documentation laravel supports out of box only  *single*, *daily*, *syslog* and *error* log logging modes.
I am wondering if is there way to use something between single and daily? I do not want to have daily log files and also do not like idea to have one big file. I would like to have possibility to specify threshold. For example 20 Mb and when this size is reached then to create new log file.
Does anybody has solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper log rotation facility that is available in your OS of choice for that.

On linux machine - [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

On Mac OS X - [newsyslog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/newsyslog.8.html)

[`RotatingFileHandler`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php#L19) in the [`monolog`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) package, which Laravel uses for logging, intended to be just as a workaround.

> Stores logs to files that are rotated every day and a limited number of files are kept.
>   This rotation is only intended to be used as a workaround. Using logrotate to
>   handle the rotation is strongly encouraged when you can use it.